# BigQuery GA360 linked dataset not in a project

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

We have a Google Analytics 360 link to BigQuery, but the ga_sessions_* tables are showing up in a new project that is in between the selected project and the Public Datasets. This new project has the name of the project ID instead of the GCP project name as usual. Like below (details changed);
[image: issue with dataset and project]

We cannot create any new datasets in this new project and it is not visible to us in Data Studio (even though we have the necessary credentials).

Normally, a project allows you to create a dataset:
[image: project options]

But with this project there are no such options:
[image: our aberrant project]

If anyone could shed some light on this situation it would be great. We would really like to create more datasets in our project.

ps. I was also not able to query this GA360 project until I entered a billing account into my own personal project which is not related to this GA360 project.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Can you share some screenshots to make it clearer as to what the problem is?

Comment: Screenshots added.

Comment: How did you create the link from GA to BigQuery? Was it created by someone else? This looks like someone else's project where you only have read access. For example, you will see the same on the public projects because you don't own those projects.

Comment: It was created by someone else, but I have Owner, BigQuery Admin and Project Billing Manager permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to interact with the project ("project-id-182938") from the display panel, and not as the project actually selected in BigQuery.

Make it the selected project by switching to it:

[image]

Then you should all the options appear normally (as long as you have the right permissions as you say you do).